# OpenRasta Default Codec

Tags: c#, rest, openrasta

I want to set a default codec in OpenRasta for all requests. i.e. When no other codec has been found using other methods, I want to use a custom JSON codec as the default.  How do you wire this up in the pipeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ResourceSpace.Has.ResourcesOfType<object>()
                 .WithoutUri
                 .TranscodedBy<MyCustomCodec>()
                 .ForMediaType("application/json");
```

That should do it.

Comment: I'm not seeing a ForContentType extension method anywhere.  There is a ForMediaType extension, however, but this:

            ResourceSpace.Has.ResourcesOfType<T>().
                WithoutUri.
                AsJson(). //custom for the codec
                ForMediaType("application/json");

Still returns a 406.

Comment: markdown ate the angle brackets. ResourcesOfType<object>() is the one you want, and the method is indeed ForMediaType :)